# Rstudio cannot launch properly with conda environment in Linux cluster

Tags: rstudio, conda

I am trying to launch a Rstudio session with a conda environment activated in a remote linux cluster. The commands are

```
$conda activate sc-tutorial
$rstudio
```

I get the following errors:

```
"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.desktopHooks.notifyRCrashed')"
QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
setNativeLocks failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

and a blank R screen like the following:
[image: Blank R screen]

Without the conda environment activated, Rstudio can be properly launched.

The OS is CentOS 7 and The rstudio version is 1.1.423. Without the conda environment activated,

```
ldd /usr/bin/rstudio
```

gives:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd18b0a000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
libQt5Network.so.5 => not found
libQt5WebChannel.so.5 => not found
libQt5WebKit.so.5 => not found
libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 => not found
libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => not found
libQt5Quick.so.5 => not found
libQt5Positioning.so.5 => not found
libQt5Sensors.so.5 => not found
libQt5Svg.so.5 => not found
libQt5Xml.so.5 => not found
libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5 => not found
libQt5Qml.so.5 => not found
libQt5Sql.so.5 => not found
libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => not found
libQt5DBus.so.5 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdbf6482000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fdbf627f000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fdbf607a000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fdbf5e72000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fdbf5c5c000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdbf5954000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdbf5652000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdbf543c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdbf506e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdbf669e000)
```

And with the conda environment activated, the ldd command gives:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff723f5000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => not found
libQt5Gui.so.5 => not found
libQt5Network.so.5 => not found
libQt5WebChannel.so.5 => not found
libQt5WebKit.so.5 => not found
libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 => not found
libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => not found
libQt5Quick.so.5 => not found
libQt5Positioning.so.5 => not found
libQt5Sensors.so.5 => not found
libQt5Svg.so.5 => not found
libQt5Xml.so.5 => not found
libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5 => not found
libQt5Qml.so.5 => not found
libQt5Sql.so.5 => not found
libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => not found
libQt5DBus.so.5 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f15b1440000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f15b123d000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f15b1038000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f15b0e30000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f15b0c1a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f15b0912000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f15b0610000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f15b03fa000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f15b002c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f15b165c000)
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So the `ldd` output is exactly the same? I don’t see how it even works in either case, since it can’t find Qt.